# I can't use \lewis with chemfig

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I've got a simple but tough problem : Texmaker does not recognize `\lewis` !

When I compile, it says : `Undefined control sequence. \lewis...`
I use chemfig of course. I've restarted my computer, a PC with Windows 10. I've tried `\Lewis`.

Can you help ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{chemfig} 
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} 

\begin{document} 
    \lewis{2.,0} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you using it this way? `\chemfig{... \lewis ...}`? Or just within the plain text?

Comment: Hi Werner, I tried both.

Comment: Then you should show a complete minimal example that replicates your problematic behaviour. Can you do that?

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{chemfig}
 \usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

 \lewis{2.,0}
 
\end{document}

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: What is your desired output? The code compiles fine for me. Produces a `0` with a dot in position 2.

Comment: Thanks. I've learned to do what I need with \chemfig and its OK now.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the manual. The macros `\lewis` does not belong to chemfig anymore since version 1.6a.

If you want to use `\lewis` instead of `\charge` (which is not recommended), you have to load the file named `chemfig-lewis.tex` with `\input`.

Comment: Hi nino,Where can I find this file ?

Comment: @Nic22 [CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf) or `texdoc chemfig` if you are on TeX Live.

Comment: I've used the \input{chemfig-file.tex} command, but the file is 'not found'. As I understand it, Texmaker needs to find it on my computer. The file is not loaded. (But maybe there is something I don't understand. I'm not a native english speaker.) The problem remains...

Answer (score 1):

you should download chemfig-lewis.tex at link below. After that, you move to
any folder, then you can text:
\input{../extra/chemfig-lewis}
Because I put chemfig-lewis.tex in extra folder
Goodluck!

https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/generic/chemfig/